# Results Box displays "Nothing matches your search" even before executing a search

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

I am configuring a results box for only a portion of my SharePoint 2013 site. Initially I came across the problem that the results box would display results even before any searches were executed. I've fixed that, but now the results box is displaying **Nothing here matches your search** even before a user searches for anything. 
Is there a way to disable this or change to a different text? My users will be confused if they see that message without even searching for anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might push you in the right direction. Please find below links and let me know if this fixes issue.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicolasu/archive/2013/07/04/sp2013-removing-the-quot-nothing-here-matches-your-search-quot-for-good.aspx

Not sure if you were using a web part but here's another one that might help with the issue.

- https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/sharepoint-2013-remove-nothing-here-matches-your-search-from-search-results-web-part/

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that in a little bit and will get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I want the error/warning and sometimes i don't so i simply include some simple css on the page where i don't want it. Not generally a good practice but sometimes it suffices.

```
#NoResult { 
  display: none; 
}
```